# System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown triggers application rescaling

Tags: c#, .net

Seems to be a bug in PresentationCore.dll in Windows .Net Framework

When I run this code, the application will change scaling if the monitor is set up with scaling greater than 100%:

```
    if (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown (System.Windows.Input.Key.LeftCtrl))
    {
     … Some code
    }
```

The scaling occurs with the size of the window, while the text usually retains the size.

I Have tested this with several versions of .Net: 4.5.2, 4.7.2 and 4.8.

Are there any alternative methods to find out if the Ctrl Key has been pressed?

Comment: Can you add a Tag for the UI Framework you are using, like `wpf`, `uwp`, `xamarin` or so?

Comment: What’s the code in the block?

Comment: Put anywhere: `[assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness]`

Comment: What’s the code in the block? – 

Any code at all. It is det test itself that hack the scaling of the applikationb

Comment: [assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness]  
Put it in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, and it seems to work well

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this.
Uses this code instead:

```
    public static bool IsCtrlKeyPressed()
    {
        bool retVal = false;
        var key = Control.ModifierKeys;
        if (key != null)
            retVal = key == Keys.Control;
        return retVal;
    }
```